# Using next-auth to authorize custom, non JS, API's?

Tags: next-auth, next.js13

**Setup**

I'm implementing a nextJs full-stack application - let's call it "app".

Im using next-auth to create authentication using the [Google](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google) and [Apple](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/apple) providers.
I'm also using the [Supabase](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/supabase) adapter so data is persistent ().

I pretty much followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/EdYQ9fF-hz4) without enabling RLS.

**problem**

Now I have a bunch of different APIs, that are not written in JS, and I want to be able to authorize them for only users authenticated to "app".

authorize = When the frontend is sending the token to the non-JS API, it will be able to verify this user sent a valid token (user signed in)

How can I do it?

**My solution attempts**

Option 1:

it looks like using the [GET /api/auth/session](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#get-apiauthsession) EP, automatically exposed by next-auth is a solid solution.

But Im missing two things:

- How do I invoke it? (params, body, etc)
- Is it actually secure?

Some resources I tried:

- [Tutorial from docs](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials#add-auth-support-to-a-nextjs-app-with-a-custom-backend-external--)
- [SO question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902602/how-to-securely-connect-my-next-js-frontend-with-next-auth-to-my-springboot-back)
- [SO question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288809/is-this-the-correct-and-secure-way-to-connect-next-js-nextauth-with-a-django-r?rq=2)
- [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/ttoxfc/auth_with_existing_backend/)